# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '$' has already been declared

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am getting the following error in my JQuery code on a WordPress site.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '$' has already been declared
```

## Background

In WordPress, sometimes the `$` identifier has not been defined as jQuery. So, you have to manually set `$` equal to jQuery so you can use `$` as shorthand in your code.

I added the simple code `var $ = jQuery;` to the top of my script, and that fixed the problem initially. However, recently I've been getting the `has already been declared` error shown above. Based on some Googling, I've tried a lot of things, and came up with the following code to try to catch this problem. But I still get the same error. The `try...catch` isn't helping at all, nor is the `if typeof...`

```
try {
  if (typeof $ !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("$ is already defined");
  } else {
    console.log("$ is not defined");
    var $ = jQuery;
  }
}
catch(err) {
  console.log("Error caught: " +  err.message);
}
```

## Disclaimers

I know the cause of this issue. Some previous script has already declared the variable `$` in the global `window` context. It is likely a plugin that is doing this. However, I can't guarantee that it will always be properly declared, so I can't just remove my declaration. Also, since this is a syntax error, I'm guessing that my `try...catch` and my `if typeof...` are basically useless.

## What I Need

I'm looking for a way to check if `$` is already declared, and then declare it *only if it isn't already declared*.
I know, this is bad coding style, but unfortunately this is WordPress and I don't have control over the entire code base. Another plugin may or may not have declared it, and that's the situation I'm in. I'd apprecaiate an answer if anyone knows!

Comment: Dollar is commonly used by other JavaScript libraries. If you must use it (and not some other alias, or just `jQuery`), Wrap your code in `jQuery(function($){}`. This applies the alias just to the scope of that function wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

> "unfortunately this is WordPress and I don't have control over the entire code base."

Ummm, this is a bold claim and i don't think it's necessarily true!

Having said that, what you asked for, in the "What I Need" section of your question is going to make your life harder down the road and it's not recommended. if you think `$` from jquery is in conflict with `$` from other javascript libraries, then use the following workflow in your wordpress project:

1. Make sure that `jquery` is actually being loaded onto your page by (code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme):

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_files');

function your_theme_files()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

2. As @isherwood suggested in the comments, wrap your `jquery` code into the following syntax to make sure `$` being used is actually the `$` from `jquery`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( $ => {

  // WRITE YOUR JQUERY CODE HERE!

});
```

By using the workflow i just mentioned:

1. Your code is going to be easier to read and maintain.
2. There won't be any conflicts between `$` signs from different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If `try...catch` instruction doesn't return demanded value (whether it's an error or a assignment), it means that you are expecting it's call after the process has stopped.

You must place your script on top of your scripts in  section. 
I believe that the shortest way to do so is by using the [Theme Editor](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-editor/) plugin.

Your way of checking `$` is okay. You could use `instanceof` operator to make sure it's instance of a function. I strongly suggest to do that at top of everything.